# Showing via Calculus methods that $f(x)=x^3-3x-1$ has all three roots in $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=x^3-3x-1$, how do we prove all three of these roots lie in $\Bbb R$ using calculus methods? I am unsure what the lecturer would have been intending.

(This is to determine that the splitting field for the polynomial over $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$ itself - and I am aware we can apply Cardanos method from algebra)

Comment: Maybe repeated used the the Intermediate Value Property. Clearly $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = \pm\infty$, so if you can show that $f$ has local extrema at $x_1 < x_2$ with $f(x_1) > 0 > f(x_2)$ you will be done.

Comment: It's been awhile since I have looked at this, so I will check it out. Does this guarantee the roots don't lie in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Yes. By the hypothesis above, there is is one root in each interval $(-\infty, x_1), (x_1, x_2), (x_2,\infty)$

Comment: Study the variations of this function?

Comment: @SimonS: Make it an answer?

Answer (score 2):

First note that respectively, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = \pm\infty$.

We also have that $f'(x) = 3(x^2 - 1)$ and $f(-1) = +1, f(1) = -3$ are local extrema.

By the Intermediate Value Property, there is at least one root in each interval $(-\infty,-1), (-1,1), (1,\infty)$. As $f(x)$ is a third order polynomial there are most three real roots. Hence there must be one root in each of those intervals.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this solution is proving rigorously what you could tell from a graph intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the (dominant, but there are no other) binomials of that polynomial and forming their product
$$
g(x)=(x^2-3)(x+\tfrac13)=x^3+\tfrac13x^2-3x-1
$$
we get a close-by polynomial with known roots $-\frac13$ and $\pm\sqrt3$. Generously enclose these by intervals and show that also the original equation has a sign change in these intervals.

---

$-\frac12<-\frac13<0$: $\quad f(-\frac12)=\frac38$ and $f(0)=-1$

---

$-2<-\sqrt3<-\frac32$: $f(-2)=-3$ and $f(-\frac32)=\frac18$

---

$\quad \frac32<\sqrt3<2$: $\qquad f(\frac32)=-\frac{17}{8}$ and $f(2)=1$